Laravel, Orchid: Toast messages are not shown
There is my screen method, but the Toast message doesn't show (but in older project Toast messages work normally)
    public function save(Model $model, ModelRequest $request)
    {
        $request->validated();
    
        $model->fill($request->get('model'))->save();
    
        Toast::success('Success!');
    
        return redirect()->route('level.index');
    }

What could be the reason?
I tried to update Orchid from ^14.0.3[14.15.0] to ^14.0.3[14.21.1], but Toast still doesn't work
